# Bounding box of 3D object in the 2D preview canvas in react-three-fiber

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want to display a rectangle around each 3D object once the user selects them.

Is there a way to get the bounding box of a 3D object as a projection to the 2D canvas?